# Sprockets::FileNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, communityengine

I am working with [CommunityEngine](https://github.com/bborn/communityengine)

Here i faced this problem.

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Base#site_index
```

//in my gemfile i use:

```
gem 'community_engine', github: 'bborn/communityengine' , branch:  "rails4"
```

i use gem `'sprockets', '~> 2.12.1'`
it depends on `'sprockets', '~> 2.10.0'` then i change it to `gem 'sprockets', '2.10.0'`
Still not working ...

```
(C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/communityengine-3d086183561a/app/views/shared/_end_javascript.html.haml where line #1 raised: 
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'
  (in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/communityengine-3d086183561a/app/assets/javascripts/community_engine.js:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were using a broken version of CommunityEngine. Please try updating your gem (your issue was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/bborn/communityengine/commit/106638ad15c60eb743e60458b3ff8388fce58b00)).